# Exclude files from require.context of Webpack

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I'm trying to include in with `require.context` of Webpack all the files that should be covered by my Istanbul reporter.

I would like to include/require all the files under `app` that have not the `.test.js` extension.

```
// internals/testing/test-bundler.js
const context = require.context('../../app', true, /^.*(?!(\.test|internals.*))\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

My files structure is:

```
app/components/
app/containers/
app/decorators/
app/orm/
app/pages/
app/store/
app/tests/
app/utils/
app/app.js
app/reducers.js
app/routes.js
internals/testing/test-bundler.js
```

Obviously my regex doesn't work because inside the coverage report I see all the `.test.js` files and even the `internals/testing/test-bundler.js` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to be aware after what part the negative lookahead employs it's rejection. If you do it right after the first forward slash it works fine.

And with that you want to reject `.*test` after the slash, instead of just `test` directly behind it.

```regex
/^(?!internals).*\/(?!.*test).*\.js$/
```

Or more specific not allowing `internals` in the path name.
Nor ending with `test.js`:

```
^(?!.*(?:internals|test.js$)).*\.js$
```

Comment: testing with the paths from his sample, your answers returns only `app/app.js` ?

Comment: It will return paths in any directory but not `internals/*`. And they won't have `test` after the first slash.  So in that sense, `test/internals.js` would still pass. but that's easy to change in the regex.

Comment: This is correct, but beware, it is still very slow and can cause memory leaks in big codebases...

Answer (score 0):

Even if exclude `node_modules` from `require.context`, `webpack` will still look into directories recursively, which is quit time consuming. I've encountered heap out of memory in a similar case.

I think it should be a better way not to install `node_modules` for each module. But keep the `node_modules` other place and specify the location in `wepback` `module.resolve`. Save source code and dependencies separated.

Comment: That's what I noticed too, especially with in pnpm monorepos, where packages have individual node_modules, as opposed to relying on hoisting of the top node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have ensured a more useful regression for excluding files with the suffix `*-spec.js` or files inside a `test` folder

```js
/^((?<!test\/).(?!-spec))+\.js$/.test('a.js'); // => true
/^((?<!test\/).(?!-spec))+\.js$/.test('a-spec.js'); // => false

/^((?<!test\/).(?!-spec))+\.js$/.test('lib/a.js'); // => true
/^((?<!test\/).(?!-spec))+\.js$/.test('lib/a-spec.js'); // => false

/^((?<!test\/).(?!-spec))+\.js$/.test('lib/test/a.js'); // => false
/^((?<!test\/).(?!-spec))+\.js$/.test('lib/test/a-spec.js'); // => false
/^((?<!test\/).(?!-spec))+\.js$/.test('test/lib/a.js'); // => false
/^((?<!test\/).(?!-spec))+\.js$/.test('test/lib/a-spec.js'); // => false
```

Answer (score -1):

What about simply filtering your paths with a simple use of `filter` ?

Fiddle:

```js
var paths = [
'app/components/',
'app/containers/',
'app/decorators/',
'app/orm/',
'app/pages/',
'app/store/',
'app/tests/',
'app/utils/',
'app/app.js',
'app/reducers.js',
'app/routes.js',
'internals/testing/test-bundler.js',
'app/blablabla.test.js'
];

var result = paths.filter(function(e,i){
   return (e.startsWith('app/') && !e.endsWith('.test.js'))
});

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
   console.log(result[i]);
```