# Webpack - Require.context -How to require all .js files except `_test.js` in a directory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

My goal was to create a file that would

1. Require all of the JS files in a directory that didn't end in `_test.js`
2. Do a `module.exports` equal to an array of module names returned from those view files.

I thought I had it with this:

```
// Automagically crawls through this directory, finds every js file inside any
// subdirectory, removes test files, and requires the resulting list of files,
// registering the exported module names as dependencies to the myApp.demoApp.views module.
var context = require.context('.', true, /\/.*\/.*\.js$/);
var moduleNames = _.chain(context.keys())
  .filter(function(key) {
      console.log(key, key.indexOf('_test.js') == -1);
    return key.indexOf('_test.js') == -1;
  })
  .map(function(key) {
      console.log("KEY", key);
    return context(key)
  })
  .value();
module.exports = angular.module('myApp.demoApp.views', moduleNames).name;
```

#2 is working as intended

#1 Unfortunately I was naive. While the module names are filtered out, this still requires all of the files with `_test` so the test files end up in my built code.

I tried to fix this by updating the regex but JS doesn't support regex negative-look-behind and I'm not regex savvy enough to do it without that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude files from require.context of Webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075646/exclude-files-from-require-context-of-webpack)

Comment: It provided enough info for me to solve my problem. Thanks for that!

Comment: You welcome. Close your question as duplicate in this case

Comment: See my answer below. Do you think it's different enough to warrant sticking around? I feel like this is a popular use-case for anyone using webpack and the `index.views.js` convention, which is popular enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I was able to use the answer in Slava.K's comment to answer my question. Here's the final code below. I had to include `(?!.*index)`  in the regex because this code was including itself `index.views.js`.

```
var context = require.context('.', true, /^(?!.*index).*\/(?!.*test).*\.js$/);

var moduleNames = _.chain(context.keys())
  .map(function(key) {
    return context(key)
  })
  .value();

module.exports = angular.module('myApp.demoApp.views', moduleNames).name;
```