# Nuxt - Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#'

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, assets, nuxt.js

Why do I get this warning below for:

```
<img :src="getImgUrl(post.thumbnail.src)" :alt="post.thumbnail.alt">

  methods: {
    getImgUrl(pic) {
      return require( '~/assets/' + pic )
    }
  }
```

Warning on the terminal:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)                                               friendly-errors 16:58:06
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> # ASSETS
| 
| **This directory is not required, you can delete it if you don't want to use it.**
                                                                                                  friendly-errors 16:58:06
 @ ./assets sync ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/work/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/work/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./pages/work/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the file's content that errored out you can see that it's a markdown file. If you check your `assets` folder there is a `README.md` file. This is the one that webpack fails to "understand".

Why webpack tries to parse markdown files? Well, in your dynamic `require` you have specified that you may request any file that is inside `~/assets`, so webpack has to parse all the files it encounters there.

You can fix this by either:

- Deleting the `README.md` file
- Specifying which extension you may want to require, so webpack can tweak its matcher:

  `require( '~/assets/' + pic + '.jpg')`

  this one is pretty limited, as now you can only use `jpg` images, and you have to strip away the extension when calling the function.
- Using [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) which allows you to match files based on a RegEx (in this case all files that **don't** end on `.md`)

  ```js
  getImgUrl(pic) {
    let context = require.context('~/assets/', false, /^(?!.*\.(?:md)$).*/);
    return context('./' + pic);
  }
  ```

If you are working with subdirectories you may need to change the second argument (`useSubdirectories` in the docs) to `true`. Also you may need to tweak the `./` concatenation for duplicated slash.

Function based on [Webpack - Require.context -How to require all .js files except `_test.js` in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745947/webpack-require-context-how-to-require-all-js-files-except-test-js-in-a-d) and https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-book/issues/80#issuecomment-216068406

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the second option probably is the least practical. But I get this error for the third option `Cannot find module './/images/sample-1.jpg'`. My image source is something like `src: '/images/sample-1.jpg'`

Comment: it should be set to `true` - `require.context('~/assets', true, /^(?!.*\.(?:md)$).*/)`